# Ошибка java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError в веб-приложении

Tags: java-ee, исключения, servlet, tomcat, fileupload

Использую Tomcat.
При вызове post-метода возникает ошибка:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
>       org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
>       controller.PDFUpload.doPost(PDFUpload.java:40)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

При вызове другого post-метода ошибок не возникает, но при попытке реализовать возможность загрузки файлов на сервер с помощью сервлета:

```
package controller;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Игорь on 10.05.2016.
 */
public class PDFUpload extends HttpServlet {
private String filePath;
boolean isMultipart;

@Override
public void init() {
    // Get the file location where it would be stored
    Path path = Paths.get("files/file.txt");
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    filePath = path.toString();
}
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Check that we have upload request
    isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    if(!isMultipart) {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        return;
    }
    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    // Maximum file size to be uploaded
    upload.setSizeMax(10000 * 1024);

    try {
        // Parse the request to get file items
        List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

        // Process the uploaded file items
        Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
            if(!fi.isFormField()) {
                out.println(fi.getName());
            }
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

вылазит ошибка выше. Для загрузки файлов использую jar: commons-io-2.5 и commons-fileupload-1.3.1.
Добавляю в проект в библиотеки и есть в переменной среды CLASSPATH (в значение переменной добавил C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre\lib\ext\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre\lib\ext\commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar).

В чем проблема?

Comment: У web-приложения своё представление о classpath. Библиотека должна оказаться в папке WEB-INF/lib war-архива или war-папки. Или среди общих библиотек сервера приложений. Не знаю чем вы собираете свой прожект, но должна быть возможность закинуть необходимые библиотеки в WEB-INF/lib. Так же не следует забывать о зависимостях самой библиотеки, они тоже должны быть добавлены в WEB-INF/lib или в общие библиотеки сервера

Comment: Для проекта использую IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кто-то тоже столкнется с этой проблемой! Суть в том, что commons-io-2.5.jar и commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar я сбросил на диск С, а брандмауэр Windows блокировал доступ к jar-файлам во время выполнения программы, хотя до компиляции классы и были видны. Все решилось после перемещения файлов в другое место. Вот полезная ссылка:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html